# bootstrap Datepicker -set startDate and endDate in viewMode 'month'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker.I have set my date picker to viewMode:'months'.But how can set the start month and end month using a date like '01-03-2015' - '01-05-2015' so that only March,April,May should be enabled.

```
$('#monthPM').datepicker({
format: "MM",
viewMode: "months", 
minViewMode: "months",
autoclose: true,
disableDateToggle: true 
});
```

Help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
numberOfMonths: 3,
showButtonPanel: true
});
});

Here is the link for more detail
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what i need is set start date and end date in view mode Month in bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Try doing this

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -22, maxDate: "+1M +8D" });